# Multiple Asset Field Query

Tags: templating

I'm looking to see if there's a better way of querying multiple asset fields in one query, surely there is but I just can't seem to find it in the docs.

```
      {% for asset in entry.eventMediaTile.all() %}
        <a class="carousel-item white-text" href="#{{ loop.index  }}">
          <img alt="{{ entry.title }} Images" src="{{ asset.getUrl('eventImage') }}"/>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for asset in entry.eventMediaTriplet1.all() %}
        <a class="carousel-item white-text" href="#{{ loop.index  }}">
          <img alt="{{ entry.title }} Images" src="{{ asset.getUrl('eventImage') }}"/>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for asset in entry.eventMediaTriplet2.all() %}
        <a class="carousel-item white-text" href="#{{ loop.index  }}">
          <img alt="{{ entry.title }} Images" src="{{ asset.getUrl('eventImage') }}"/>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for asset in entry.eventMediaTriplet3.all() %}
        <a class="carousel-item white-text" href="#{{ loop.index  }}">
          <img alt="{{ entry.title }} Images" src="{{ asset.getUrl('eventImage') }}"/>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for asset in entry.eventMediaTriplet4.all() %}
        <a class="carousel-item white-text" href="#{{ loop.index  }}">
          <img alt="{{ entry.title }} Images" src="{{ asset.getUrl('eventImage') }}"/>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for asset in entry.eventMediaTriplet5.all() %}
        <a class="carousel-item white-text" href="#{{ loop.index  }}">
          <img alt="{{ entry.title }} Images" src="{{ asset.getUrl('eventImage') }}"/>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be suitable for your use case but you could use an [Asset query](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/asset-queries.html) to fetch assets related to your entry:

```twig
{% set assets = craft
    .assets()
    .withTransforms(['eventImage'])
    .relatedTo({
        sourceElement: entry,
        field: ['your','fields']
    })
    .all() %}

{% for asset in assets %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

(If these are your only asset fields on the entry, you don't need `field: ['your','fields']`)